# OpenCV face recognition is too slow

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I tried to use OpenCV with face_recognition to get real-time face recognition, but it end up being slow and laggy. Any help please?
Code:

```
import face_recognition
import os
import cv2
from PIL import Image

appdata = os.getenv('APPDATA') + "/Project/"
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier((appdata + "data/face_cascade.xml").replace("\\", "/"))
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Capture video (OpenCV)

def Main():
    while True: #OpenCV start video capture from webcam
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        gray_scale = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_scale, 1.5, 5)

        for x, y, w, h in faces:
            #Start face recognition (face_recognition)
            roi_color = frame[y: (y + h) - 15, x: (x + w) - 15] #This cuts the background leaving only the face
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), ((x + w) - 15, (y + h) - 15), (255, 35, 36), 2)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(roi_color) #This encodes face features and causes lag

        cv2.imshow('sysPy', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(20) == 27:
            break
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Main()
```

Also I was thinking about "`face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(roi_color)`" to not encode every frame, skip frames to reduce the lag. Thanks!

Comment: I tested it with one of standard file `cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_eye.xml"` and it works very fast on 8 years old computer. If problem is not slow computer then maybe problem is xml file with big data.

Comment: but it is file to recognize only eyes. For faces code may need more work and

Comment: I tried another face cascade, its smooth but It lags sometimes, I guess you are right.